# Translating coordinate frames? Or RGBDSLAM axis orientation?

Tags: slam, navigation, stere-image-proc, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The short version of my question is:  what's the easiest way to invert one axis of a point cloud (pointcloud2)?  I.E.  change every point from (x,y,z) to (x,y,-z).

My longer question is this:  do I have to, or am I doing something wrong?

I'm trying to use a stereo camera with  rgbdslam.  It looks to me like rgbdslam uses a different axis orientation than what stereo_image_proc is putting out.  The stero_image_proc wiki page has a diagram showing the point cloud reference frame as x-axis right, y-axis down, and z-axis forward.  It appears that rgbdslam is x-axis left.

I've got everything running, and my point cloud coming from stero_image_proc looks correct in rviz (they are in front of the camera, like they should be) .  But in rgbdslam, the points look like they're *behind* the camera.  In other words, they look like they're coming out of the screen at me rather than receding into the screen like they should.

Thanks,
-Jon

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49553/translating-coordinate-frames?--or-rgbdslam-axis-orientation?/) by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 837 on 2012-12-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vdonkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/14946/vdonkey/) on 2014-04-28**:
Hello, Jon Stephan, I'm a beginner. I want to use stereo_image_proc(call it SIP) with rgbdslam too. I can see disparity from image_view receiving topics from SIP. what should be next? rgbdslam seems listening /camera/rgb/image_rect_color & /camera/depth_registered/image_rect, but SIP don't have them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Wow, once I found an area where the cameras picked up more points, I see that it is actually working correctly.  My brain was playing tricks on me.  It's really hard get the right perspective - I wish rgbdslam had a grid reference plane like RVIZ.

---

Originally posted by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) with karma: 837 on 2012-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-12-09**:
Noted. Will be done in the next version.

**Comment by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) on 2012-12-09**:
Cool!  Thanks!